# elasticsearch JDBC -RIVER java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jdbc-river

I am using elasticsearch "1.4.2" with river plugin on an aws instance with 8GB ram.Everything was working fine for a week but after a week the river plugin[plugin=org.xbib.elasticsearch.plugin.jdbc.river.JDBCRiverPlugin
version=1.4.0.4] stopped working also I was not able to do a ssh login to the server.After server restart ssh login worked fine ,when I checked the logs of elastic search I could find this error.

```
[2015-01-29 09:00:59,001][WARN ][river.jdbc.SimpleRiverFlow] no river mouth
[2015-01-29 09:00:59,001][ERROR][river.jdbc.RiverThread   ] java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
```

After restarting the service everything works normal .But after certain interval the same thing happen.Can anyone tell what could be the reason and solution .If any other details are required please let me know.

When I checked the number of file descriptor using

```
sudo ls /proc/1503/fd/ | wc -l
```

I could see it is increasing after every time . It was 320 and it now reached 360 (keeps increasing) . and

```
sudo grep -E "^Max open files" /proc/1503/limits
```

this shows 65535

### processor info

```
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 62
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2670 v2 @ 2.50GHz
stepping    : 4
microcode   : 0x415
cpu MHz     : 2500.096
cache size  : 25600 KB
siblings    : 8
cpu cores   : 4
```

### memory

```
MemTotal:       62916320 kB
MemFree:        57404812 kB
Buffers:          102952 kB
Cached:          3067564 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:          2472032 kB
Inactive:        2479576 kB
Active(anon):    1781216 kB
Inactive(anon):      528 kB
Active(file):     690816 kB
Inactive(file):  2479048 kB
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5253072/java-unable-to-create-new-native-thread

Comment: I have option MAX_OPEN_FILES=65535 in my init.d in elasticsearch

Answer (score 1):

Do the following

1. Run the following two commands as root:

   ulimit -l unlimited
   ulimit -n 64000
2. In `/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml` make sure you uncomment or add a line that says:

   bootstrap.mlockall: true
3. In `/etc/default/elasticsearch` uncomment the line (or add a line) that says `MAX_LOCKED_MEMORY=unlimited` and also set the `ES_HEAP_SIZE` line to a reasonable number. Make sure it's a high enough amount of memory that you don't starve elasticsearch, but it should not be higher than half the memory on your system generally and definitely not higher than ~30GB. I have it set to `8g` on my data nodes.

In one way or another the process is obviously being starved of resources. Give your system plenty of memory and give elasticsearch a good part of that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to analysis your server log. Maybe In: `/var/log/message`