# Elasticsearch is not running

Tags: elasticsearch

I tried running ubuntu elasticsearch at 12:04, after I install and run is OK, but i'm check `sudo /etc/init.d/elasticsearch status` there I see message `elasticsearch is not running`. and I tried to run in the browser to `localhost: 9200` also failed. 
help me please..

Answer (score 2):

It will not start automatically after you install it for good reason. You don't want it to accidentally join a cluster configured to use multicast discovery. See my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28556125/elasticsearch-jdbc-river-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-unable-to-create-new-nativ/28844094#28844094) for information on the basics for configuring elasticsearch.

In addition to that post, also make sure you set the following two options in `/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml`:

1. `cluster.name: some-other-name`
2. `discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false`

After you have done that, start it by running:

```
sudo service elasticsearch start
```

You should almost always disable multicast because on a local testing environment you only have one node so you don't need it, and in a production environment it's just bad practice since nodes accidentally joining the cluster can break things (trust me, I've had this happen and it's a headache).

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `sudo /etc/init.d/elasticsearch start`?