# Dag-scheduler-event-loop java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread

Tags: java, apache-spark

I get the following error from spark-driver program after running for 5-6 hours. I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and open-jdk-8.

```
Exception in thread "ForkJoinPool-50-worker-11" Exception in thread "dag-scheduler-event-loop" Exception in thread "ForkJoinPool-50-worker-13" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
    at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:714)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.tryAddWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1672)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.deregisterWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1795)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:117)
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
    at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:714)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.tryAddWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1672)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.signalWork(ForkJoinPool.java:1966)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.push(ForkJoinPool.java:1072)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.fork(ForkJoinTask.java:654)
    at scala.collection.parallel.ForkJoinTasks$WrappedTask$class.start(Tasks.scala:377)
    at scala.collection.parallel.AdaptiveWorkStealingForkJoinTasks$WrappedTask.start(Tasks.scala:443)
    at scala.collection.parallel.AdaptiveWorkStealingTasks$WrappedTask$$anonfun$spawnSubtasks$1.apply(Tasks.scala:189)
    at scala.collection.parallel.AdaptiveWorkStealingTasks$WrappedTask$$anonfun$spawnSubtasks$1.apply(Tasks.scala:186)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.parallel.AdaptiveWorkStealingTasks$WrappedTask$class.spawnSubtasks(Tasks.scala:186)
    at scala.collection.parallel.AdaptiveWorkStealingForkJoinTasks$WrappedTask.spawnSubtasks(Tasks.scala:443)
    at scala.collection.parallel.AdaptiveWorkStealingTasks$WrappedTask$class.internal(Tasks.scala:157)
    at scala.collection.parallel.AdaptiveWorkStealingForkJoinTasks$WrappedTask.internal(Tasks.scala:443)
    at scala.collection.parallel.AdaptiveWorkStealingTasks$WrappedTask$class.compute(Tasks.scala:149)
    at scala.collection.parallel.AdaptiveWorkStealingForkJoinTasks$WrappedTask.compute(Tasks.scala:443)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.RecursiveAction.exec(RecursiveAction.java:160)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doJoin(ForkJoinTask.java:341)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.join(ForkJoinTask.java:673)
    at scala.collection.parallel.ForkJoinTasks$WrappedTask$class.sync(Tasks.scala:378)
    at scala.collection.parallel.AdaptiveWorkStealingForkJoinTasks$WrappedTask.sync(Tasks.scala:443)
    at scala.collection.parallel.ForkJoinTasks$class.executeAndWaitResult(Tasks.scala:426)
    at scala.collection.parallel.ForkJoinTaskSupport.executeAndWaitResult(TaskSupport.scala:56)
    at scala.collection.parallel.ParIterableLike$ResultMapping.leaf(ParIterableLike.scala:958)
    at scala.collection.parallel.Task$$anonfun$tryLeaf$1.apply$mcV$sp(Tasks.scala:49)
    at scala.collection.parallel.Task$$anonfun$tryLeaf$1.apply(Tasks.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.parallel.Task$$anonfun$tryLeaf$1.apply(Tasks.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.parallel.Task$class.tryLeaf(Tasks.scala:51)
    at scala.collection.parallel.ParIterableLike$ResultMapping.tryLeaf(ParIterableLike.scala:953)
    at scala.collection.parallel.AdaptiveWorkStealingTasks$WrappedTask$class.compute(Tasks.scala:152)
    at scala.collection.parallel.AdaptiveWorkStealingForkJoinTasks$WrappedTask.compute(Tasks.scala:443)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.RecursiveAction.exec(RecursiveAction.java:160)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
    at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:714)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.tryAddWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1672)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.deregisterWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1795)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:117)
```

This is the error produced by the Spark Driver program which is running on client mode by default so some people say just increase the heap size by passing the `--driver-memory 3g` flag or something however the message `"unable to create new native thread"`  really says that the JVM is asking OS to create a new thread but OS couldn't allocate it anymore and the number of threads a JVM can create by requesting OS is platform dependent but typically it is 32K threads on a 64-bit OS & JVM.

when I did ulimit -a I get the following

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 120242
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 120242
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

cat /proc/sys/kernel/pid_max

```
32768
```

cat /proc/sys/kernel/threads-max

```
240484
```

"unable to create new native thread" clearly means it has nothing to do with heap. so I believe this is more of a OS issue.

Comment: Have you tried limiting the amount of threads that your pool can create? Or, instead, manually creating a pool that has a specified amount of threads (N times your amount cores)? Regardless of the error, I see little point of creating 32k threads, seems like a waste. Also, make sure you are using a single pool and not creating one in a loop.

Comment: please see my answer below

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There seems to be a bug in the usage of ForkJoinPool in Spark 2.0.0 which is creating way too many threads. Specifically in the UnionRDD.scala which is used when you are calling a window operation on Dstream.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-17396 so according to this ticket I upgraded to 2.0.1 and it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

In Java you can stumble upon two kind of Out of Memory errors:

1. The `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError Java heap space error` : This
   exception will be triggered when the application attempts to
   allocate more data into the heap space area, but there is not enough
   room for it. Although there might be plenty of memory available on
   your machine, you have hit the maximum amount of memory allowed by
   your JVM, which can be set through the -Xmx parameter
2. The `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Unable to create new native thread`
   happens whenever the JVM asks for a new thread from the OS. If the
   underlying OS cannot allocate a new native thread, this
   OutOfMemoryError will be thrown.

**1) Check Threads system wide settings**

The /proc/sys/kernel/threads-max file provides a system-wide limit for the number of threads. The root user can change that value if they wish to:

```
$ echo 100000 > /proc/sys/kernel/threads-max
```

You can check the current number of running threads through the /proc/loadavg filesystem:

```
$ cat /proc/loadavg
0.41 0.45 0.57 3/749 28174
```

Watch the fourth field! This field consists of two numbers separated by a slash (/). The first of these is the number of currently executing kernel scheduling entities (processes, threads); this will be less than or equal to the number of CPUs. The value after the slash is the number of kernel scheduling entities that currently exist on the system. In this case you are running 749 threads

**2) Check number of processes per user**

On a Linux box, threads are essentially just processes with a shared address space. Therefore, you have to check if your OS allows you enough processes for user. This can be checked through:

```
ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 515005
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 4096
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 10240
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 1024
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

The default number of process per users is 1024 by default. At this point we will count the number of processes running. The number of processes running can be counted with a  ps output:

```
$ ps -elf | wc -l  
220
```

This number however does not consider the threads which can be spawned by a process. If you try to run ps with a -T you will see all of the threads as well:

```
$ ps -elfT | wc -l  
385
```

As you can see the process count increased significantly due to threads. Normally this is never any type of problem, However in Java based applications this can cause your system to run into system limits! Let's continue our investigation. Let's see how many Threads are spawned by your JBoss Process. You can do it in at least two ways:

```
$ ps -p JBOSSPID -lfT | wc -l
```

The above shell will return the number of Lightweight Processes created for a Process indicated by the PID. This should match with the Thread Dump count generated by jstack:

```
$ jstack -l JBOSSPID | grep tid | wc -l
```

Now you should have evidence or not that you need to increase the number of processes for the user. This can be done with the following command:

```
$ ulimit -u 4096
```

**3) Check your threads PID limit**

Once that you have counted the number of threads, then you should verify that you are not hitting system limits, specified by the kernel.pid_max limit parameter. You can check this value by executing:

```
$ sysctl -a | grep kernel.pid_max  

kernel.pid_max = 32768
```

**4) Reduce the Thread Stack size**

Another option which you can use, if you are not able to modify the OS settings is reducing the stack size. The JVM has an interesting implementation, by which the more memory is allocated for the heap (not necessarily used by the heap), the less memory available in the stack, and since threads are made from the stack, in practice this means more “memory” in the heap sense (which is usually what people talk about) results in less threads being able to run concurrently.

First of all check the default Thread Stack size which is dependent on your Operating System:

```
$  java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep ThreadStackSize
     intx ThreadStackSize                           = 1024                                {pd product}
```

As you can see, the default Thread Stack Size is 1024 kb in our machine. In order to reduce the stack size, add “-Xss” option to the JVM options. In JBoss EAP 6 / WildFly the minimum Thread stack size is 228kb. You can change it in Standalone mode by varying the JAVA_OPTS as in the following example:

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Xms128m -Xmx1303m -Xss256k"
```

In Domain Mode, you can configure the jvm element at various level (Host, Server Group, Server). There you can set the requested Stack Size as in the following section:

```
<jvm name="default">
            <heap size="64m" max-size="256m"/>
            <jvm-options>
                <option value="-server"/>
                <option value="-Xss256k"/>
            </jvm-options>
</jvm>
```

### Resource Link:

[How to solve java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-monitoring/how-to-solve-javalangoutofmemoryerror-unable-to-create-new-native-thread)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! Just an FYI, There isn't any JBOSS process. I am using spark

Comment: Also I did go through the other SO links you posted  but anyways really appreciate the effort. I also posted my ulimit -a. The question is really now is how do I limit the threads to solve the issue?

Comment: @user1870400 Would you please increase the limit and check [`ulimit –c unlimited`]. For more you can check http://www.computerworld.com/article/2693414/setting-limits-with-ulimit.html

Comment: And also you can go through this tutorial: http://landoflinux.com/linux_ulimit_command.html. Hope it may help you.

Comment: I did increase the limit. so should I look at the core dump file when my java process throws the java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Unable to create new native thread error again?

Answer (score 0):

### Root Cause Analysis:

Threads within the JVM need some elbow room to carry out the work they are summoned to deal with. When there are more threads than there is room in memory we have built a foundation for a problem:
[image]
The message `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Unable to create new native thread` means that the **Java application has hit the limit of how many Threads it can launch**.

### What is causing it?

You have a chance to face the `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Unable to create new native thread` whenever the JVM asks for a new thread from the OS. Whenever the underlying OS cannot allocate a new native thread, this `OutOfMemoryErro`r will be thrown. The exact limit for native threads is very platform-dependent thus we recommend to find out those limits by running a test similar to the below example. But, in general, the situation causing java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Unable to create new native thread goes through the following phases:

1. A new Java thread is requested by an application running inside the JVM
2. JVM native code proxies the request to create a new native thread to the OS
3. The OS tries to create a new native thread which requires memory to be allocated to the thread
4. The OS will refuse native memory allocation either because the 32-bit Java process size has depleted its memory address space – e.g. (2-4) GB process size limit has been hit – or the virtual memory of the OS has been fully depleted
5. The java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Unable to create new native thread error is thrown.

### Give me an example

The following example creates and starts new threads in a loop. When running the code, operating system limits are reached fast and `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Unable to create new native thread` message is displayed.

```
while(true){
    new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000000);
            } catch(InterruptedException e) { }        
        }    
    }).start();
}
```

The exact native thread limit is platform-dependent, for example tests on Windows, Linux and Mac OS X reveal that:

1. 64-bit Mac OS X 10.9, Java 1.7.0_45 – JVM dies after #2031 threads have been created
2. 64-bit Ubuntu Linux, Java 1.7.0_45 – JVM dies after #31893 threads have been created
3. 64-bit Windows 7, Java 1.7.0_45 – due to a different thread model used by the OS, this error seems not to be thrown on this particular platform. On thread #250,000 the process was still alive, even though the swap file had grown to 10GB and the application was facing extreme performance issues.
   So make sure you know your limits by invoking a small test and find out when the java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Unable to create new native thread will be triggered

### What is the solution?

Occasionally you can bypass the Unable to create new native thread issue by increasing the limits at the OS level. For example, if you have limited the number of processes that the JVM can spawn in user space you should check out and possibly increase the limit:

```
[root@dev ~]# ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
--- cut for brevity ---
max user processes              (-u) 1800
```

More often than not, the limits on new native threads hit by the OutOfMemoryError indicate a programming error. When your application spawns thousands of threads then chances are that something has gone terribly wrong – there are not many applications out there which would benefit from such a vast amount of threads.
One way to solve the problem is to start taking thread dumps to understand the situation.

### Resource Link:

https://plumbr.eu/outofmemoryerror/unable-to-create-new-native-thread

There are more others answer is available here:

1. [How to solve java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native
   thread](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-monitoring/how-to-solve-javalangoutofmemoryerror-unable-to-create-new-native-thread)
2. [OutOfMemoryError: Unable to Create New Native Thread – Problem
   Demystified](https://dzone.com/articles/outofmemoryerror-unable-create)
3. https://stackoverflow.com/a/16789621/2293534
4. [Java: Unable to create new native thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5253072/java-unable-to-create-new-native-thread)