# Threads Error Memcached cloud Heroku Java

Tags: java, heroku, memcached, java-threads, java-memory-leaks

**Background**

We are developing a Java service in Heroku with 1 dyno, which is using Memcached cloud.

**Issue**

Meanwhile we were developing and testing it, It was working fine. However, when we decided to test it in a real environment, It started to return the following error:

`java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread 
    java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method) 
    java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:717) 
    net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection.<init>(MemcachedConnection.java:306)    net.spy.memcached.DefaultConnectionFactory.createConnection(DefaultConnectionFactory.java:209)
    net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClient.<init>(MemcachedClient.java:209) 
    Memcached.<init>(Memcached.java:34) 
    Main.lambda$main$1(Main.java:101) 
    spark.SparkBase$1.handle(SparkBase.java:311) 
    spark.webserver.MatcherFilter.doFilter(MatcherFilter.java:159) 
    spark.webserver.JettyHandler.doHandle(JettyHandler.java:60)

    org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:179)

    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:136)
    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:451) 
    org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.run(HttpChannel.java:252)
    org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:266)

    org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.run(AbstractConnection.java:240)

    org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:596)

    org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:527) 
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)`

We didn't have so much clients to arrive at 256 process or threads (limit of 1 dyno)

**Workaround**

We don't know it yet

**Code**

    `<!--Main-->
    //...
    try {
       memcached = new Memcached ();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
       memcached  = null;
    }
    //...`

```
<!--Memcached-->
public class Memcached {
private MemcachedClient memcachedClient;
private boolean connected;

public Memcached () throws Exception {
    setConnected(true);

    try {
        AuthDescriptor ad = new AuthDescriptor(new String[] { "PLAIN" },
                new PlainCallbackHandler(System.getenv("MEMCACHEDCLOUD_USERNAME"),
                    System.getenv("MEMCACHEDCLOUD_PASSWORD")
                )
        );

        setMemcachedClient(new MemcachedClient(
                new ConnectionFactoryBuilder()
                        .setDaemon(true)
                        .setFailureMode(FailureMode.Retry)
                        .setProtocol(ConnectionFactoryBuilder.Protocol.BINARY) //this is the line 34 
                        .setAuthDescriptor(ad).build(),
                AddrUtil.getAddresses(System.getenv("MEMCACHEDCLOUD_SERVERS"))
        ));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // the Memcached client could not be initialized
        setConnected(false);
        throw new Exception ("{\"ErrorCode\":20,\"Portal\":\"Memcached\",\"ResponseCode\":\"\",\"Message\":\""
                + ex.getMessage() + "\"}");
    }
}

public String get (String service, String fromCurrency, String toCurrency) {
    if (!isConnected()) {
        return null;
    }

    try {
        return (String) getMemcachedClient().get(service + ";" + fromCurrency + ";" + toCurrency);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}

public boolean set (String service, String fromCurrency, String toCurrency, String value) {
    if (!isConnected()) {
        return false;
    }

    try {
        double hour = Double.parseDouble(System.getenv("TIME_CACHE_HOUR"));
        getMemcachedClient().set(service + ";" + fromCurrency + ";" + toCurrency, (int)(60 * 60 * hour), value);

        return true;
    }catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}

public boolean isConnected () {
    return this.connected;
}

private void setConnected (boolean connected) {
    this.connected = connected;
}

private MemcachedClient getMemcachedClient () {
    return this.memcachedClient;
}

private void setMemcachedClient (MemcachedClient memcachedClient) {
    this.memcachedClient = memcachedClient;
}
```

> Anyone knows how can we fix this error?

EDIT: I have read the post [Java: Unable to create new native thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5253072/java-unable-to-create-new-native-thread), but It isn't our problem. We checked the attributes that they said there, but we have good values. However, I could see that everytime that memcached is initialized, It create a new thread, but that thread isn't deleted when the service stop. There's the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: Unable to create new native thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5253072/java-unable-to-create-new-native-thread)

Comment: Such as I wrote in my EDIT, that post don't fix our problem. Nevertheless, thanks, we could see the real probleam thank to that, but We don't know how oto fix it.